# GridView scrollable with Fixed Header and Footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a GridView in a div with Vertical scroll, but I want to fix the Header and the footer when the user scrolls...I Googled it, but the majority of answers are old and never worked fine or worked only in IE.

Someone have a method for work in every browsers ?
I use asp.net 4.0 and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a very good component, extended of GridView and fix my problem. If someone has the same problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59160/Extended-GridView-with-Fixed-Header-and-Pager